# How can we capture HTTPWebRequest in .net core using Fiddler

Tags: api, debugging, .net-core, fiddler

I am sending http request to sandbox api which sometimes returns positive response but sometimes it returns bad request with same request data and headers. So I want to debug this request using fiddler during I run the .net core code hitting that api.

But I am not able to find any way to that. Can any one please help me out for the same. I have tried following code to do this:

```
  var requestMessage = GenerateRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, uri, query);
        requestMessage.Content = new ObjectContent<T>(value, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), (MediaTypeHeaderValue)null);           
        IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);            
        HttpClient.DefaultProxy = proxy;
        return _httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

but fiddler is not capturing this api request.

Comment: You can try to enable "Act as System proxy on startup" in Fiddler settings to see if the used code uses proxy settings at all. You should at least see a `CONNECT` request.

Comment: I have reinstalled fiddler and added entry 'ReverseProxyForPort' in registry by regedit, so it started capturing web requests